# http.ServerRequest.prototype

Tags: prototype

I want to add my own method to http.ServerRequest object. But http.ServerRequest is null. I tried `requset.prototype.testtest = function() { console.log('aaaaa'); };` in server callback. It answers 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'testtest' of undefined'. How to add method to ServerRequest objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http.IncomingMessage.prototype.testtest = function() { ... }

ServerRequest is a IncomingMessage object